# tf.placeholder not reading rbg colour parameter

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to feed a single 300 x 300 x 300 tensor into a placeholder in tensorflow, and although I'm using `imgs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 300, 300, 300, 3])` I'm getting the `ValueError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tfvgg.py", line 265, in <module>
prob = sess.run(vgg.probs, feed_dict={vgg.imgs: train_data})
File "/home/entelechy/tfenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 717, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
File "/home/entelechy/tfenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 894, in _run
% (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 300, 300, 300) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(1, 300, 300, 300, 3)'
```

I'm new to tensorflow, what's needed to make the input dimensions compatible with the placeholder?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sess = tf.Session()
    imgs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 300, 300, 300, 3])
    vgg = vgg16(imgs, None, sess)

    # Data
    INPUT_FOLDER = 'data/cubed_data/pp/play'
    images = os.listdir(INPUT_FOLDER)
    images.sort()

    train_data = []
    for i in images:
        im = np.load(INPUT_FOLDER + "/" + i)
        train_data.append(im)

    prob = sess.run(vgg.probs, feed_dict={vgg.imgs: train_data})
    preds = (np.argsort(prob)[::-1])[0:5]
    for p in preds:
        print(class_names[p], prob[p])
```

Comment: Does your image data have color information?

Comment: The input is just an ndarray of 300 x 300 x 300, so maybe not.  What would be the way to deal with this though?  It still has a single colour channel, so would still be [1, 300, 300, 300, 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tensor you try to feed has the shape of (1, 300, 300, 300), and your placeholder has the shape (1, 300, 300, 300, 3). Both must have the same shape, so change your placeholder to:

```
imgs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 300, 300, 300])
```

**edit**

With the new error message we are getting closer to the roots of the problems.

First of all you must bring your input to the shape (1, 300, 300, 300, 1). The first dimension is already there since you put your image into a list. The last dimension must be added:

```
im = np.load(INPUT_FOLDER + "/" + i)
im = np.reshape(im, (300, 300, 300, 1))
train_data.append(im)
```

The placeholder must be set to:

```
imgs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 300, 300, 300, 1])
```

Your second problem is that your network expects a 3D image with 3 channels (rgb 3D data), but your image has only one channel. You must change the kernel dimension of the first convolution in the network (apparently the convolution is in the file "tfvgg.py" at line 30).

You must find where the kernel of that convolution is created and change its dimensions to [whatever, whatever, whatever, 1, whatever]. Right now the 2nd last dimension is 3 but it must be changed to 1. Thereafter it should work with 1 image.

If you later want to input multiple images at the same time in a batch, you will have to adjust the first dimension of the placeholder to:

```
imgs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [number_of_images, 300, 300, 300, 1])
```

or for arbitrary image numbers you can also use:

```
imgs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 300, 300, 300, 1])
```

The network you use might only support 1 image, but it probably supports arbitrary batch sizes.

Comment: I'd already tried that but then it inputs a 2d tensor to the net instead of 3d.  The input is a 3d ndarray of 300 x 300 x 300

Comment: @McLeodx without the code of vgg16 it was impossible to tell what the real problems were, but with the second error message (which is gone now?) I think I found them

Comment: Worked perfectly.